# Shuffling of Arrays in Python while maintaining the same keys

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2 arrays. **traces_** is an array of size 2560 x 2500 and **x_** is an array of size 2560 x 1

I want to shuffle(randomize) both the arrays such that for each of my traces(i,:), all the 2500 values are mapped correctly to the corresponding x(i)?

I implemented the following but it didn't work

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
traces, x = shuffle(traces_,x_,random_state=0);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from numpy.random import permutation, seed
seed(0) # for reproducibility 
rand_idx = permutation(len(x))
rand_trace = trace[rand_idx]
rand_x = x[rand_idx]
```